# How to create master template for html pages

Tags: jquery, html, master-pages, dreamweaver

I have some ten html pages with same header ,footer ,left and right navigation tabs can i have one master template so that i will refer header and footer and navigation tabs from each page without using any asp controls .

Comment: You really should not be using Dreamweaver to generate HTML...

Comment: I meant to say that can i create html pages on the clientside without referring any serverside controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with your index.html page and go to File > Save as Template. Then on the newly created template page you can set everything but the header, footer, and navigation as editable regions. Then re-create all the other pages from the template(File > New > Page From Template)  and copy the editable content from your previously created pages to the editable region in the newly created pages. Once you transfer the content over to the pages created from the template, if you change the header or footer or navigation on the template it will update all pages created from that template.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to give every page its body tag a different class, like for example `<body class="home">, <body class="news">, <body class="about">` etc. You could then use jQuery to highlight the navigation menu item with the corresponding id, like for example when you are at the page with class 'about' your should highlight the menu item with id 'about'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you be more clear about the concept , can you suggest any article regarding this

Comment: It would look something like this: http://www.simplebits.com/bits/tab_rollovers.html where in this example 'guides' is selected being `li#tguides` which should correspond with `body.tguides`.